# Cannot install python3.6 on Debian 4.9 VM

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, debian-based

I'm running a Debian VM (4.9.189-3+deb9u1) on the Google cloud. I want to run a script on this instance; the script works fine on my local machine (Mac OSX Mojave 10.14.6; python 3.6.8). However, when I run it on the VM I get an error that seems to relate to the fact that my the VM runs python 3.4 when the script needs python 3.6+.

Here's the problem. When I run `python -V`, the response is `Python 3.7.4`. However, when I try to install the library supporting the script I want to run

```
    pip3 install --user --upgrade -e 
    git+https://github.com/twintproject/twint.git@origin/master#egg=twint
```

I get

`twint requires Python '>=3.6.0' but the running Python is 3.5.3`.

I have tried [changing the default python as detailed here](https://exitcode0.net/changing-the-default-python-version-in-debian/); this doesn't seem to work––in fact, python 3.6 isn't even visible as an option when I query `ls /usr/bin/python*`. Can anyone offer some advice on how to proceed here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have multiple Python versions available. If `python -V` gives you `Python 3.7.4`, you can use:

```
$ python -m pip install --user --upgrade -e git+https://github.com/twintproject/twint.git@origin/master#egg=twint
```

to invoke `pip` from that same Python interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for this! In the end, the easiest solution turned out to be installing anaconda and making that the default python; for whatever reason, this was much easier than doing an install of python on its own, and also made the dependencies much easier to work with, too.